How to move the last row to the top in a table in MySQL?
I have a row in the following table which is the first row but added to the table at the end and now I'd like to modify the table in a way to show employee ids in order starting by number 1.

Issue:
(
  SELECT * FROM employees
  ORDER BY employee_id DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id != (SELECT MAX(employee_id) FROM employees)
);

The above code is the solution from chatGPT but still doesn't move the last row to the top. Any clues?

use ORDER BY to order results of any SQL statement

to get all employees that are order by Id, simply use  SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY employee_id ?

Does the PRIMARY KEY exists in your table? define employee_id as PRIMARY KEY - in most cases simple SELECT * FROM table returns the rows sorted by PK expression.

@Akina Thanks! I think this is final solution (making employee_id as PRIMARY_KEY) since it keeps the order even after closing MySQL and opening it again.

SQL tables are inherently unordered sets. You can never assume nor trust the order of rows returned from a query that doesn't explicitly order them.
If you want the employee with employee_id of 1 to come first, you could order by it:
SELECT   *
FROM     employees
ORDER BY employee_id


This code ordered the table as I wanted however when I close MySQL and run it again, the order goes back to before, showing row 1 at the end of the list. Is there a way to keep it there on top even after quitting MySQL?

@PeymanH You missed the point in the first sentence. There is no notion of order in an SQL table. You can only order a specific query, not the table itself.

If you want to receive some definite rows ordering then you must apply ORDER BY expression which provides needed rows ordering.
In your case - you want the row with the highest employee_id value to be placed on the top of the output.
You may use, for example, the next method - obtain greatest value in the subquery and compare each row value with the value returned by the subquery, if equal then place the row first. The comparing result is either TRUE (which is 1) or FALSE (which is 0), so you'd order by this comparing result in DESCending order which puts the row(s) with the expression value of FALSE first.
SELECT * 
FROM employees
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(employee_id) AS employee_id
             FROM employees ) AS max_employee_id
ORDER BY employees.employee_id = max_employee_id.employee_id DESC


Tried this and did not fix the issue.

@PeymanH Maybe you did something wrongly? See fiddle.

I copied and pasted your code but did fix the issue.

Try this query statement:
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM employees
      ORDER BY employee_id DESC
      LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM employees
      WHERE employee_id != (SELECT MAX(employee_id) FROM employees)
      ORDER BY employee_id
    );


Maintaining the order of records when using UNION ALL is not documented.

Thank you for your quick response @akina, I added the ordering into the select SQL Query. It will select first then union after that the result.

If you have any conclusions, Please share.

Not documented == not guaranteed. So somewhere you may meet an unpleasant surprise...

@Nilesh: Specifying the ORDER BY at between the ); solves the sorting problem when having a UNION of UNION ALL. Ordering of the individual SELECT statement is not needed (Only needed when you also have a LIMIT)

Tried this and did not fix the issue.

@PeymanH: see final query in this DBFIDDLE

@Luuk Got it, thanks!
